# Dual Boot Ubuntu on my Windows 10

Tags: xubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Can anyone help me? I am currently a Windows 10 user on my laptop and I want to dual boot my laptop so I can have Ubuntu and Windows 10. Can anyone give me an instruction on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the Ubuntu ISO file [Ubuntu 20.04](https://ubuntu.com/#download)
2. Download Rufus for Making USB bootable [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).
3. Create the usb bootable using rufus and ubuntu iso.
4. Restart the system and go to laptops boot manager, and change the boot sequence, Make the boot from usb/ pendrive at the top following the instruction given on the right side of the bootmanager (In case you don't know the how to enter into boot manager google it.)
5. Save and exit from boot manager
6. Now your laptop will start showing menu for installing the ubuntu , follow the steps and choose carefully,
   step 6: In the installation Type choose " Install along side Windows"

that's it.

Comment: The first thing to check is whether your laptop is running in UEFI mode. With Win10 it probably is, but you should check anyway. Type *msinfo32* from *search programs* from Start menu in W10, and it will tell you. It's also advisable to disable secure boot before installation. Also would help to know make and model of laptop.

Comment: Hello I already successfully installed Ubuntu thank you! I would like to ask on how to remove Ubuntu on my desktop if I just wanted to in case (but will not probably).